# Issue with jQuery tabs and Slidshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, slideshow

I have a issue that I need to resolve. That includes code for jQuery tabs and slideshow composition.

#### HTML

```
<div>
    <div style="display: block;"> 
        <a href="http://www.implanteperio.com.br/megaimersao/"><img src="images/banner/banner_mega_junho.jpg" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="http://implanteperio.com.br/cursos2013_estrangeiros.php"><img src="images/banner/banner_extranjeros_cirurgia_plastica_periimplantar.jpg" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="http://implanteperio.com.br/cursos2013_recobrimento_radicular.php"><img src="images/banner/banner_imersao_recobrimento_radicular.jpg" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/banner/banner_novos_cursos.jpg" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="http://implanteperio.com.br/cursos2013_education_week.php"><img src="images/banner/banner_education2_esgotado.jpg" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="http://implanteperio.com.br/casos03_2013.php"><img src="images/banner/banner_casos_maio.jpg" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
    <!--<div>
        <a href="casos07_2012.php"><img src="images/banner/03_(10.2012).jpg" border="0" /></a>
    </div>-->
</div>

<div class="slidetabs"> 
    <a class="current" href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
// What is $(document).ready ? See: http://flowplayer.org/tools/documentation/basics.php#document_ready

$.noConflict();
chamaTab = $(function() {$(".slidetabs").tabs($(".images > div", {effect: 'fade', fadeOutSpeed: "slow", rotate: true })).slideshow({autoplay: true, interval: 5000}); });
```

The code just doesn't work! This problem needs to be fixed.. But I don't have any idea how to resolve it.

P.S: I'm new to programming jQuery and Javascript, so I ask that for a little patience.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you get any errors in the developer console?

Comment: I don't see jQuery included anywhere on the page.

Comment: What are you expecting this to do?

Comment: @projeqht Typos aren't a great reason to downvote (better to edit)... that being said, he did that because you aren't allowed to put "Problem" in the title.

Comment: Would-be editors: Substituting 'issue' for 'problem' in titles doesn't really address the point of the rule, which is that titles should explain the problem or issue, not mention that there is one. That goes without saying.

Comment: Where is `.slidetabs`?

Comment: @isherwood Thank you for that. I try to keep the text as similar to the original as possible when editing... and the asker didn't actually list the problem they had... so it made it hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something seems off with your initialization function. Try this:

```
chamaTab = $(function() {
    $(".slidetabs").tabs( {
        effect: 'fade', 
        fadeOutSpeed: "slow", 
        rotate: true 
    })
    .slideshow({autoplay: true, interval: 5000}); 
});
```